# MySql count number of users who voted for each option

Tags: mysql

I have following `vote` table structure:

```
id   user_id    question_id    value    
1      232         1             A
2      324         1             B
3      323         1             A
```

where `value` can only be either A or B

I need to get result in the following format

```
question_id      A          B
  1              34         45
  2              13         24
```

Where `A` is number of user who chose option A, `B` is number of user who chose option B

Comment: you are trying to do a pivot table. Plenty of answers to the same question already on SO. Also, what have you tried so far? Show us the code you tried

Comment: @LelioFaieta i had no idea how to solve this. but thanks for 'pivot table' tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
select
  question_id,
  sum(if(value = 'A', 1, 0)) as A,
  sum(if(value = 'B', 1, 0)) as B
from vote
group by question_id;
```